# What should function signature look like to pass in 2D arrays of arbitrary size?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function that I want to accept 2D arrays of arbitrary size.

So if I have the following:

```
char names[100][10];
char values[100][5];
```

What should my function signature look like?

I tried:

`void myFunc(char* names[], char* values[]);`
and
`void myFunc(char** names, char** values);`

But then I get `argument of type "char(*)[10]" is incompatible with parameter of type "char**".`

I tried:

`void myFunc(char names[][], char values[][]);`

But then I get `an array may not have elements of this type.`

The only thing that works is 
`void myFunc(char names[100][10], char values[100][5]);`

But then it's not arbitrary size. I'm aware that I'll need to pass a size parameter as well, but I can't even get to that yet.

Comment: Life would be easier if you were permitted to use the standard library.

Comment: I hate to flag duplicates when the duplicate has so many terrible, terrible answers...

Comment: Long ago I decided that the answer to this question is "You don't." Use a C++ structure of some kind to map 2D (or more) indexes onto a single 1D array allocation. Or possibly multiple 1D arrays.

Comment: I'd rather do `struct myPair { char name[10];char value[5]; }; myPair pairs[100]`; probably you are actually looking for `std::map`

Comment: @ZanLynx I'm starting to think you're right. MD arrays in C++ are a trash fire.